# Structure of an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Say I have an app that has a fixed layout: one button and a few labels. It makes sense not to use multiple view controllers throughout the app since I have the same button and labels. I don't want to copy and paste them because their look and style will never change. If I decide to change their look later on, I would have to go through every single view controller and this is a bad practice (as it is with copying and pasting code).

Though, I want to be able to let the user go back and forward "layouts" the app, but this code doesn't let me do that:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        enterFirstLayout()
    }

    func enterFirstLayout() {
        // do things such as change labels' text property
        exitFirstLayout()
    }

    func exitFirstLayout() {
        // do things
        enterSecondLayout()
    }

    func enterSecondLayout() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What can I do to avoid creating multiple view controllers and giving the user the possibility to skip and go back to a specific layout of the app?

Comment: You should decouple the fixed *layout* (presentation) of your app from the *content* that is being presented. You can keep just one view controller class, but make multiple instances of that class presenting different data.

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks @jtbandes. What if one layout differs a little bit from the others? Say I need to call a function just in one layout, and not the others.

Comment: The questions you're asking are too vague for good answers. This might not be 100% relevant to your problem, but I would recommend exploring the design of [ResearchKit](http://researchkit.org/docs/index.html) which has a concept of "steps" and "tasks" that might bear some resemblance to whatever it is you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to achieve something like wizard that you can go back and foreword thru screens.

In this case I would use a `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Build one custom cell that represents your single 'screen' layout than build a simple datasource as an array of custom objects. Datasource should contains for example all label's content as a `String` variables.

Nice and elegant code.

You get scrolling animation and swipe gesture detection for free. If you like you can add your custom fancy animation.

This is my solution. Going back to your question, if you want to do this your way, you can for example use subclassing. Build your base view controller class with all layout configured and labels exposed as public, read-only variables, then inherit from this class. Please keep in mind that subclassing is tightest possible coupling.

Other option is to build this view controller once and reuse with different dataset.

So decision is your. I would go in 1, 3, 2 order :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `UICollectionView` solution looks promising but how do I switch between custom cells?

Comment: You'll get swipe gesture for free. You can disable it if you want. To manually trigger switching you can use `setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, animated animated: Bool)` and set `contentOffset.x = numberOfPage * CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)`